# Passing a parameter to a programmatically created User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, controls

Let me just preface this with: I Googled high and low for this, and found many examples and solutions, and I still can't figure this out.

**In a .aspx.cs code behind file, I have the following:**

```
NewsArticleList listall = NewsArticleManager.GetListAll();
foreach (NewsArticle x in listall)
{
    Control c1 = (NewsArticleContainer)LoadControl("~/UserControls/NewsArticleContainer.ascx");
    ((NewsArticleContainer)c1).PopulateWithNewsArticle(x);
    mynewspanel.Controls.Add(c1);
}
```

I have a method in the User Control called PopulateWithNewsArticle() that accepts a NewsArticle, and populates the User Control's web controls accordingly:

```
public void PopulateWithNewsArticles(NewsArticle x)
{
   lbltitle.Text = x.Title;
   lblcategory.Text = x.Category;
   //...etc.
}
```

Now this works, this is fine.  But what I would like to learn/understand, is how I can pass the NewsArticle x to the User Control when I LoadControl(), so that upon creation of the User Control, I can unpackage the NewsArticle on the User Control's Page_Load, and set the web control properties from right when the User Control is instantiated as opposed to doing it after instantiation with the PopulateWithNewsArticle method (like I have it now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our you can expose public property `NewsArticle`  in the `NewsArticleContainer.ascx`, so you will have initialization code like this:

```
var control = (NewsArticleContainer)LoadControl("~/UserControls/NewsArticleContainer.ascx");
control.NewsArticle = x;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
Control c1 = 
(NewsArticleContainer)LoadControl(typeof(NewsArticleContainer),new object[]{ x });
```

This one is an overloaded of `Page.LoadControl()`, It has this syntax

```
public Control LoadControl(
    Type t,
    Object[] parameters
)
```

After that you would have to create a valid constructor for your UserControl too, which could be something like this

```
class NewsArticleContainer:System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
   public NewsArticleContainer(NewsArticle x)
   {
      // Some cool code stuff here
   }
}
```

For more on this [go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewtd66a0.aspx).

Comment: +1 I didn't realise LoadControl could take overloaded constructors

Comment: That's awesome, thanks a lot.  My next question would be, after passing my parameter via the overloaded LoadControl(), how can I receive and unpackage those parameters at the other end, in the user control's constructor?  Does it simply just "know" to use those parameters for the constructor?

Comment: Actually it looks like the overload takes different parameters.  If you want to use the object array, you can't give it a string as the path, but you need to give it a Type.

Comment: yeah you are right thanx for notifying me. I have edited my answer.